# How format string using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, string, formatting, latitude-longitude

I have an app that consume a API. I have absolutely no control over that API, so I can not modify it, just consume it.
That API returns in json format a city name, latitude and longitude.
The problem is that by a programming error, the API return latitude and longitude with wrong format:

```
[{"Name":"River Side","Latitude":-2524544568.0,"Longitude":-5758220052.0}]
```

Obviouly, I need the Latitude and Longitude with following format:

```
-25.245445680 and -57.582200520
```

I found Javascript functions like toFixed(), but round the number.

Does somebody know how I can format correctly the string using Javascript?

Comment: Why is this api not debugged on the first place? So that lat/long are correct? Have you made a request to the developers?

Comment: As already mentioned, we have no control over the API, which was created by another group from the university. It is part of a group / individual work and is about finding solutions to problems that we can not correct from the root.

Comment: @GuillermoAcosta Did you find an acceptable solution to your problem?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like longitude and latitude are being sent as numbers, correct? Would it be possible just to do something like `var lat = data.Latitude / 100000000`?

Comment: Yes, Dargue. They are always sent as numbers, it should be float type, but it sends as number with 1 decimal. We thought about doing division, but not all "lat" and "lon" have the same number of decimal digits. We want to find a function that takes the "integer" part of the number, and to that number (including its sign) add a point three digits from the left. And we did not find the form yet.

Answer (score 0):

Presuming that in each case and for both of lat and lon:

1. The sign is correct.
2. The digits are correct.
3. The decimal point may be in the wrong place.
4. abs(lat) <= 90
5. abs(lon) <= 180

Looking at the lat example (-2524544568.0): -252.4 is invalid. -25.2 is plausible. -2.52 is plausible IF you don't restrict points to your own country. So is -0.252. Similarly with longitude.

You also can make use of the "Name" field if you have a reasonably accurate source for a mapping from name to (latitude, longitude).